# ForbiddenAttributesError rspec create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

This one is really annoying, im probably just missing something silly. been at it for 2h now, can see whats the problem. error: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:

**order.rb**

```
has_many :item_lines
accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_lines
```

**order_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    if params[:v1_order][:item_lines_attributes].present?
      puts "attributes: "
      puts params[:v1_order][:item_lines_attributes] # {"quantity"=>"1", "net_price"=>"9.99"}
      @v1_order = V1::Order.new(v1_order_params)
      @v1_order.item_lines.build(params[:v1_order][:item_lines_attributes])
    else
      @v1_order = V1::Order.new(v1_order_params)
    end
  end

  def v1_order_params
  params.require(:v1_order).permit(:state, :vat, :order_date, :user_id, 
  :item_lines_attributes => [:quantity, :net_price])
  end
```

**order_controller_spec.rb**

```
    expect {
      post :create,
      :v1_order => {vat: 20, user_id: 1,state: 0,
      :item_lines_attributes => [quantity: 2, net_price: 3]},
       token: @user.api_key.token
    }.to change(V1::Order, :count).by(1)

      **below should also be valid, but no go **

      post :create, 
      v1_order: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:v1_order,
      item_lines_attributes: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:v1_item_line)),
```

**Factories**

```
  factory :v1_order, :class => 'V1::Order' do
    state 0
    vat 20
    user_id 1
  end
  factory :v1_item_line, :class => 'V1::ItemLine' do
    quantity 1
    net_price "9.99"
  end
```

keep getting this:

```
 Failure/Error: post :create,
 ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
 ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

Answer (score 0):

Define def v1_order_params inside the private function.

Private
 def v1_order_params
....
 end
End

Comment: it is private, I just didn't copy that part. And I don't think that would make a difference

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can try to change:

@v1_order.item_lines.build(params[:v1_order][:item_lines_attributes])

To:

@v1_order.item_lines.build(v1_item_lines_params)